# Symfony 6 authentification

Tags: symfony

Good morning everyone
Please i am block on authentification.The debug log :
[my debug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8EGu.png)

here is my entity code

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable,PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface,PasswordHasherAwareInterface
```

{
/**
* @var int
*
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $id;

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $fullName;

/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
 */
protected $gender;

/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
protected $firstname;

/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $lastname;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;


/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="notes", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
protected $notes;

/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="locked", type="boolean")
 */
protected $locked = false;


/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="json")
 */
private $roles = [];

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastLogin", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $lastLogin;

/**
 * Random string sent to the user email address in order to verify it.
 *
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="confirmationToken", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $confirmationToken;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="passwordRequestedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $passwordRequestedAt;

/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sf_user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $groups;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $group;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $birth_date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $blood_group;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $phone;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $license;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Specialty::class, inversedBy="users")
 */
private $speciality;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Schedule::class, mappedBy="user")
 */
private $schedules;


/**
 * User constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->locked = false;
    $this->roles = array();
    $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->schedules = new ArrayCollection();
}


public function getId() 
{
    return $this->id;
}


public function setFullName(string $fullName): void
{
    $this->fullName = $fullName;
}

// le ? signifie que cela peut aussi retourner null
public function getFullName() 
{
    return $this->fullName;
}

public function getUsername() 
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): void
{
    $this->username = $username;
}

public function getGender() 
{
    return $this->gender;
}

public function setGender(string $gender): void
{
    $this->gender = $gender;
}    

public function getNotes() 
{
    return $this->notes;
}

public function setNotes(string $notes): void
{
    $this->notes = $notes;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(?string $email): void
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword($password = null): void
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

public function getFirstname(): ?string
{
    return $this->firstname;
}

public function setFirstname(string $firstname): void
{
    $this->firstname = $firstname;
}

public function getLastname(): ?string
{
    return $this->lastname;
}

public function setLastname(string $lastname): void
{
    $this->lastname = $lastname;
}

public function getLocked(): ?bool
{
    return $this->locked;
}

public function setLocked(bool $locked): void
{
    $this->locked = $locked;
}

/**
 * Retourne les rôles de l'user
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles;

    // Afin d'être sûr qu'un user a toujours au moins 1 rôle
    if (empty($roles)) {
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    }

    foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
        $roles = array_merge($roles, $group->getRoles());
    }
   // die(var_dump($roles, array_unique($roles)));
    return array_unique($roles);
}

public function setRoles(array $roles): void
{
    $this->roles = $roles;
}

/**
 * Retour le salt qui a servi à coder le mot de passe
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getSalt(): ?string
{
    // See "Do you need to use a Salt?" at https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html
    // we're using bcrypt in security.yml to encode the password, so
    // the salt value is built-in and you don't have to generate one

    return null;
}

/**
 * Removes sensitive data from the user.
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function eraseCredentials(): void
{
    // Nous n'avons pas besoin de cette methode car nous n'utilions pas de plainPassword
    // Mais elle est obligatoire car comprise dans l'interface UserInterface
    // $this->plainPassword = null;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function serialize(): string
{
    return serialize([$this->id, $this->username, $this->password, $this->locked]);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function unserialize($serialized): void
{
    [$this->id, $this->username, $this->password, $this->locked] = unserialize($serialized);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setLastLogin(\DateTime $time = null)
{
    $this->lastLogin = $time;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setConfirmationToken($confirmationToken)
{
    $this->confirmationToken = $confirmationToken;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setPasswordRequestedAt(\DateTime $date = null)
{
    $this->passwordRequestedAt = $date;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Gets the last login time.
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getLastLogin()
{
    return $this->lastLogin;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getConfirmationToken()
{
    return $this->confirmationToken;
}

 /**
 * Gets the timestamp that the user requested a password reset.
 *
 * @return null|\DateTime
 */
public function getPasswordRequestedAt()
{
    return $this->passwordRequestedAt;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isPasswordRequestNonExpired($ttl)
{
    return $this->getPasswordRequestedAt() instanceof \DateTime &&
           $this->getPasswordRequestedAt()->getTimestamp() + $ttl > time();
}

/**
 * @param $group
 * @return $this
 */
public function addGroup($group)
{
    $this->groups[] = $group;
```

//        $group->addUser($this);

```
    return $this;
}


/**
 * @param $groups
 */

public function setGroup($group = null)
{
    $this->addGroup($group);
}


/**
 * @param $groups
 */

public function clearGroups()
{
    $this->groups->clear();
}
/**
 * @param $groups
 */

 /**
 * @param $groups
 */

public function setGroups(ArrayCollection $groups = null)
{
    if ($groups !== null) {
        $this->groups->clear();
        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            $this->addGroup($group);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getGroups()
{
    return $this->groups;
}

public function hasRole($role) {
    foreach($this->getGroups() as $grp) {
        if($grp->hasRole($role)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Get group
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getGroup()
{
    return $this->group;
}

public function hasGroup($name = '')
{
    return in_array($name, $this->getGroupNames());
}

public function containGroup(Group $group)
{
    return $this->groups->contains($group);
}

public function __toString() {
    return $this->getUsername().' - '.$this->getFirstname().' '.$this->getLastname();
}

public function removeGroup(Group $group): self
{
    if ($this->groups->contains($group)) {
        $this->groups->removeElement($group);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function getUserIdentifier(): string 
{
    return (string)$this->email;
}

public function getPasswordHasherName(): ?string
{
    return null; // use the default hasher
}

public function getBirthDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->birth_date;
}

public function setBirthDate(?\DateTimeInterface $birth_date): self
{
    $this->birth_date = $birth_date;

    return $this;
}

public function getBloodGroup(): ?string
{
    return $this->blood_group;
}

public function setBloodGroup(?string $blood_group): self
{
    $this->blood_group = $blood_group;

    return $this;
}

public function getAddress(): ?string
{
    return $this->address;
}

public function setAddress(string $address): self
{
    $this->address = $address;

    return $this;
}

public function getPhone(): ?string
{
    return $this->phone;
}

public function setPhone(string $phone): self
{
    $this->phone = $phone;

    return $this;
}
```

security.yaml

```
security:
enable_authenticator_manager: true
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
password_hashers:
    App\Entity\Security\User: 'auto'
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
providers:
    main:
        entity: 
            class: App\Entity\Security\User
            property: email 
firewalls:
    main:
        provider: main
        pattern: "^/gestion"
        form_login:
            provider: main
            login_path: adminlogin
            check_path: adminlogin
            default_target_path: /gestion
            target_path_parameter: go_to
        logout:
            path: adminlogout
            target: adminlogin
            invalidate_session: true
        remember_me:
            secret: "%env(APP_SECRET)%"
            lifetime: 2232000
            path: /gestion
        entry_point: form_login
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/gestion/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/gestion, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, ROLE_ADMIN] }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_PATIENT
```

when@test:
security:
password_hashers:
App\Entity\Security\User: 'auto'
# By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
# important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
# are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
# reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
algorithm: auto
cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon

Each time i try to log in , i receive authentification successfull after what i get access denied
enter code here

Comment: Start by taking the time to edit your question and format the code properly.  The very last sentence indications that authentication is successful?  You see the user logged in in the profile bar?  In which case it is the authorization that is failing.  Important difference.  If it is indeed a case of getting access denied then start by commenting out the access control stuff and see if that is the problem.

Comment: What about the getRoles() and 'ROLE_USER' at least!?

Answer (score 0):

You are successfully authenticated then you can't access the wanted url, a possible reason for this is your access control, please verify the role of the user used to connect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).